# Isabelle/HOL: Induction fails because the assumption about the inductive predicate is not the first assumption

Tags: isabelle, hol

I have the following definitions:

```
inductive star :: "('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" for r where
 refl: "star r x x"
|step: "r x y ⟹ star r y z ⟹ star r x z"
```

and

```
inductive star' :: "('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" for r where
 refl': "star' r x x"
|step': "star' r x y ⟹ r y z ⟹ star' r x z"
```

I want to prove the lemma `star' r x y ⟹ star r x y`. I have transitivity of `star`.

I follow the guide: [concrete-semantics](http://concrete-semantics.org/). There (ex. 4.3 as of 2023.12.04) it is hinted that I would need auxiliary lemma and that the induction wouldn't work because the assumption about the inductive predicate (`⋀x y z. r x y ⟹ star r y z ⟹ star' r y z ⟹ star' r x z`) is not the first assumption (`star r x y ⟹ star' r x y`), i.e. `r x y ≠ star r x y`.

My understanding is that I need to make a lemma `h` of the sort: `∀x y z. r x y ⟶ star r y z ⟶ star' r y z ⟶ star' r x z ⟹ ∀x y z. star r y z ⟶ r x y ⟶ star' r y z ⟶ star' r x z` and replace (i.e. simplify) it in the inductive predicate.. But I am having trouble understanding the differences between ∀ and it's meta version.. when I did such lemma and tried to use it for simplification, I got infinite loop:

```
lemma "star r x y ⟹ star' r x y"
  apply(induction rule: star.induct)
   apply (simp add: refl')
  apply (simp add: h)
```

I tried many other variants, but to be honest, those attempts were probably even worse than the one I shared just above.